# How to make an object of a class extending Enum

Tags: python, enums

I have the following Python class.

```
from enum import Enum  
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2
    green = 3
```

But when I try to create an object it

`color = Color()`

it throws an error telling

`TypeError: __call__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

What is the other expected argument.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to specify an actual color in the object creation call.

Comment: Enum acts like a static class, there is no need to instantiate it directly. Just use attributes like Color.red, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docstring in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4/file/8671f89107c8/Lib/enum.py) (note that this method is defined on the metaclass, `EnumMeta`):

> [`__call__`] is used both when an enum class is given a value to match
>   to an enumeration member (i.e. `Color(3)`) and for the functional API
>   (i.e. `Color = Enum('Color', names='red green blue')`).

The required positional argument `value` is either one of the values of an existing enumerator, or the name of a new one.

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) for the former, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) for the latter.